# Meaning and usage of /proc/[pid]/make-if-fail

Tags: linux, embedded, proc

I am currently developing inside an embedded Linux environment (kernel 3.10.0), and while goofing around in the `procfs` mount of the system I found that all processes present the following file in their `/proc/[pid]` folder:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root    root      0 Feb   22 09:10 make-it-fail
```

Just for testing, I launched from the shell `sleep 360 &` and tried to read/write with `cat` and `echo` the `make-if-fail` file. These are the results:

```
# stat /proc/[sleep_pid]/make-it-fail
    File: /proc/[sleep_pid]/make-it-fail
    Size: 0    Blocks: 0    IO Block: 1024   regular empty file
    [...]
# cat /proc/[sleep_pid]/make-it-fail
0
# echo "1" > /proc/[sleep_pid]/make-it-fail
# cat /proc/[sleep_pid]/make-it-fail
1
# stat /proc/[sleep_pid]/make-it-fail
    File: /proc/[sleep_pid]/make-it-fail
    Size: 0    Blocks: 0    IO Block: 1024   regular empty file
    [...]
```

Odd things:

1. Although `stat` claims that the file has size 0, I could read and write something there, and retrieve what I wrote.
2. The process is alive and kicking, "surviving" the reads and writes of this file. I actually expected it to ... well, fail or exit.

I understand that `procfs` is a pseudo-filesystem (therefore `stat` results might be not "real"/misleading) and that it interfaces with kernel structures, but I feel I am missing something here right now.

So, what is the purpose and usage of this file? I cannot recall seeing it in other distros (e.g. it is not in the Ubuntu that I use for development)

Comment: I found this link. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fault-injection/fault-injection.txt; as for the file, it is there because the kernel has debug mode enabled. proc is a virtual interface for kernel vars, those file inconsistencies are taken for granted.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro thanks! That is it! If you'd elaborate it more in an answer I'd accept it.

Comment: I investigated a little more and posted an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was investigating a little your questions, as I was becoming suspicious from reading this [Injecting faults into the kernel](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/fault-injection/fault-injection.txt) that make-it-fail was a flag.

Actually it is confirmed reading [Injecting faults into the kernel](https://lwn.net/Articles/209257/):

> So there are a number of options which can be used to focus the faults
> on a particular part of the kernel.
> These include:  task-filter: if
> this variable is set to a positive value, faults will only be injected
> when a specially-marked processes are running. To enable this marking,
> each process has a new flag (*make-it-fail*) in its /proc directory;
> **setting that value to one will cause faults to be injected into that
> process.**

At the end of the day, make-it-fail is a boolean flag that marks whether a conditional injection operation to several processes will be done in the related PID. So just changing it's value to 1 as you have done will have no consequences.

As for the variables/filenames themselves, the article also point outs the kernel has to be compiled with fault injection capability turned on; hence you not seeing them in other Linux machines normally.

As for proc having the file system inconsistencies, proc is a virtual file system mapping file names to internal linux structures/variables; and it is natural a file having as size 0 bytes.

From the TLDP [Linux Filesystem Hierarchy: /proc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html)

> The most distinctive thing about files in this directory is the fact
> that all of them have a file size of 0, with the exception of kcore,
> mtrr and self.